# Excel Countdown Timer with Time Extensions

Tags: excel, countdowntimer

*The Goal:*
To implement a count down timer that can add in time extensions to the end of the timer.

[The layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeC3M.png)

*Insight to the the layout:*

- The **Event** is just a drop down of events that correlates to a specific time for that event. (For this, we'll just assume it's 50 minutes.)
- **Round 1 Start** is the start time and is input by the user.
- **Round 1 End** is the end time using an excel function.
  `=IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",IFERROR(C2+VLOOKUP($A$2,Lookups!$A$2:$B$9,2), "Invalid"))`
- **Remaining Time** is the count down timer with an excel VBA to refresh it continuously
  `=IFERROR(IF(NOW()-TODAY()-D2-TIME(0,F2,0)>0,"TIME IN ROUND",IFERROR(ABS((NOW()-TODAY())-D2)+IFERROR(TIME(0,F2,0),0),"")),"")`
- **Time Extension** is the extension in minutes.

*What works:*
Without time extensions, it does what it should and when the timer reaches 0:00:00 it displays the "TIME IN ROUND" message.

*What doesn't work:*
When a time extension is added, it never reaches 0:00:00 and instead it just starts counting up as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBCXC.png). Instead it will show the "TIME IN ROUND" message after the **Time Extension** is multiplied by 2. This has never worked correctly for me even after messing with the time extension part of the formula.

Code Breakdown:
`=IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",IFERROR(C2+VLOOKUP($A$2,Lookups!$A$2:$B$9,2), "Invalid"))`
This will display blank until the Start time cell (C2) is filled. Once the start time is filled, the event is referenced to give the time duration (50 minutes).

`=IFERROR(IF(NOW()-TODAY()-D2-TIME(0,F2,0)>0,"TIME IN ROUND",IFERROR(ABS((NOW()-TODAY())-D2)+IFERROR(TIME(0,F2,0),0),"")),"")`
The first if statement, `NOW()-TODAY()-D2-TIME(0,F2,0)>0` this is just checking if the countdown timer has reached the end time.
The second if statement `ABS((NOW()-TODAY())-D2)+IFERROR(TIME(0,F2,0),0)` is verifying if there's a time extension, add the time extension value to the end time.

Comment: If you want anybody to help you, you have to help us understand what you’re doing.  (1) Describe, in English, at a high level, what you’re trying to accomplish.  (2) Explain what `D2` and `F2` are.  (You say “the only required parameter is the Start time”, so why are you referring to these two other cells?)  (3) What is “time extension”?  (4) Describe, at a technical level, how the formula is supposed to do what it is supposed to do.  (5) You use `IFERROR` ***three times!***  What errors are you expecting? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (6) Are you saying that this sometimes works, or that it previously worked?  If so, say so explicitly.  (7) Explain, in English (***and*** at a technical level), what you are doing.  (What does ‘‘add time extensions’’ mean?)  (8) Describe, in English, what is happening.  If *absolutely necessary* to supplement your description, add illustrations *that actually illustrate something.*  (Your current images are not helpful.  The first one is blank!  Is there supposed to be some animation there, that’s either too fast or too slow for me to see?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  The second image is not helpful because you don’t show which cell is `D2` and which cell is `F2`, and I don’t know what the expected / desired result is.)  (9) Have you tried using “Evaluate Formula” for debugging? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott I got a good bulk of those questions asked and clarified a ton of details. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, the question is considerably clearer now; thank you.   I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The short answer:

The `ABS()` is the problem. 
Peculiar placement of parentheses obscures the problem.

#### Longer explanation:

In

```
ABS((NOW()-TODAY())-D2)
    ↑             ↑
```

the marked parentheses don’t do any good. 
You might as well just say

```
ABS(NOW()-TODAY()-D2)
```

and it would be clearer to say

```
ABS(NOW()-(TODAY()+D2))
```

where `TODAY()+D2` is the actual (scheduled) end time of the event. 
For example, if `D2` is displayed as `16:30:00`,
that is actually stored in the worksheet as January 0, 1900 16:30:00
(which is *really* December 31, 1899 16:30:00). 
And, if today is June 27, 2021, then `TODAY()` is June 27, 2021 00:00:00,
and so `TODAY()+D2` is June 27, 2021 16:30:00.

And so `NOW()-(TODAY()+D2)` is how far away the actual (scheduled) end time
of the event is from the current time. 
*After* the (scheduled) end time of the event, this is positive. 
*Before* the (scheduled) end time of the event, this is negative. 
(***At*** the (scheduled) end time of the event, it is zero,
as you would expect for a countdown timer.)

You want to show a positive (but continually decreasing) time
before the deadline (and then zero ***at*** the deadline,
and your "TIME IN ROUND" message after the deadline). 
So taking the absolute value makes a certain amount of sense. 
But you’re taking the absolute value of the wrong thing. 
Consider: if `D2` is 16:30:00 and `F2` is 15,
that means that the deadline is really 16:45. 
Now, let me take a slightly bigger piece of your formula,
change the parentheses as I showed above, remove the `IFERROR`
and add spaces for clarity:

```
ABS(NOW()-(TODAY()+D2))   +   TIME(0,F2,0)
```

*Before* 16:30, this works correctly. 
`NOW()-(TODAY()+D2)` is how far away the (scheduled) end time (16:30) is
from the current time,
as *a **negative** value* that is increasing toward zero (as time passes). 
So the absolute value is a positive value that is decreasing (toward zero).

But, at 16:30, `NOW()-(TODAY()+D2)` becomes zero,
and then it becomes an increasing positive value. 
And, of course, `ABS(x)` equals *`x`*
when *`x`* is positive (or zero). 
So let’s plug in some numbers:

| `NOW()` | `NOW()-(TODAY()+D2)` | `ABS(NOW()-(TODAY()+D2))` | `ABS(NOW()-(TODAY()+D2)) + TIME(0,F2,0)` (the countdown value) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16:20 | −0:10<sup>1</sup> | 0:10 | 0:25 |
| 16:25 | −0:05<sup>1</sup> | 0:05 | 0:20 |
| 16:30 | 0:00 | 0:00 | 0:15 |
| 16:35 | 0:05 | 0:05 | 0:20 |
| 16:40 | 0:10 | 0:10 | 0:25 |
| 16:45 | 0:15 | 0:15 | 0:30 |

__________
<sup>1</sup> This would not be a legal free-standing value,
since Excel doesn’t like negative times. 
But it’s OK in the middle of a formula.

Of course, after 16:45, the outermost `IF` overrides all this math stuff,
and you get your "TIME IN ROUND" message.

#### Suggestions

Why would you ever want to look at `TODAY()+D2` (or `NOW()-(TODAY()+D2)`)? 
That’s the *(originally) **scheduled*** end time of the event. 
You care about the ***extended*** end time (deadline) of the event, which is

```
TODAY()+D2+TIME(0,F2,0)
```

OK, `TIME(0,F2,0)` can throw an error if `F2` is negative or non-numeric. 
So, if there’s a risk that a user will type something like “ASAP” into `F2`,
you need to guard against that with `IFERROR()`.

`NOW()-TODAY()-D2-TIME(0,F2,0)>0` is hard to read. 
It is equivalent to

```
NOW() > TODAY()+D2+TIME(0,F2,0)
```

which is (IMO) easily understood as
“compare the current time to the *extended* end time of the event”. 
(Also, it has a problem: it uses `TIME(0,F2,0)` without `IFERROR()`.)

The right half of your formula is way more complicated than it needs to be. 
We can simplify it to

```
=IF(NOW() > TODAY()+D2+IFERROR(TIME(0,F2,0),0),  "TIME IN ROUND",  (TODAY()+D2+IFERROR(TIME(0,F2,0),0)) - NOW())
```

### But…

The above has a 29-character long repeated subexpression (`TODAY()+D2+IFERROR(TIME(0,F2,0),0)`). 
Repeated subexpressions impede readability, especially if they’re long. 
The *extended* end time (deadline) of the event is a meaningful value. 
You might want to display it in a column of its own. 
But, if not that, how about a helper column? 
Put

```
=TODAY()+D2+IFERROR(TIME(0,F2,0),0)
```

into cell `Z2` (and frag/fill down to cover Column `Z`) and use

```
=IF(NOW() > Z2,  "TIME IN ROUND",  Z2 - NOW())
```

in `E2`. 
(You can then hide Column `Z` if you want.)